# Android WebView Video Download

Tags: android-webview

I am developing video downloader app, the app can download videos from all sites except youtube. for example, while the user browse for a video and clicks the play button the download url should be generated in the background. I am struck in generating download url, can anyone help me, the videos can be from sites like dailymotion, vimeo and more, thanks in advance